# Summing results returned from an INDEX array formula

Tags: excel

Say I've got a list of values in column A, and I want to add up the values from the rows 4, 8, and 99.  I put 4, 8, and 99 in cells B1:B3, and then I could do in cells C1:C3

```
{=INDEX(A:A,B1:B3)}
```

as an array formula to return the values I want, and then

```
=SUM(C1:C3)
```

to add them up.  But if I want to do that in a single cell,

```
{=SUM(INDEX(A:A,B1:B3))}
```

now it just returns the first value returned from the INDEX function.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we need to do a little trickery to force INDEX into returning an array:

```
=SUM(INDEX(A:A,N(IF({1},B1:B3))))
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Can you point me to something explaining what the N() function is doing here, exactly?